# Expanding Java SWT Tree asynchronously

Tags: java, asynchronous, tree, swt

I am having a problem with my SWT Tree. It contains many leaves what makes expanding an item very time consuming. Sometimes I even need to expand all items. Is there a way to expand it asynchronously? I have tried to use `asyncExec()` on the display putting `expandAll()` inside the `run()` method, but it didn't help. And it doesn't solve the first problem where I want to expand only one item. Any ideas?

Additional node: The slow expansion of an item happenes only the first time I expand it. All later expansions of the same item (after collapsing it) are fast.

Answer (score 2):

I solved performance issues with large trees by change the content provider to an `ILazyTreeContentProvider`. This won't help if you have to expand the full tree at once.

An alternative: Have a closer look at your content and label providers. Maybe their operations are too expensive and you can speed up things if you cache or pre-calculate some information for the tree. If, for example, you have a normal (non-lazy) content provider that loads the items from a database (one-by-one), expanding the tree will take *forever*...

Comment: I found the problem: A CheckStateProvider was the bottleneck (a CheckboxTreeViewer was used). The solution was a Hash lookup: `treeViewer.setUseHashlookup(true);` But your answer was also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the model items in the UI thread? You should ideally load your model items in a non-UI thread and then update the tree with the items in the UI thread.